# How come armies all over the world were caught so badly flat-footed?

Tags: black-tide-rising

According to the timeline of *Black Tide Rising*, the US government was aware of the plague almost instantly - not about the origin, infection sources and so on, obviously, but that something's going around and it's bad.

Uncle Tom was aware of it as an employee of BOTA, which obviously would get any info from the government - and the book says as much, actually (about the source(s)).

But USAMRIID would definitely be on top of this one, as they actually are there mainly for that reason - that is: to actively search for possible bio/chem attacks on US (widely understood).

I do get that NB San Diego, NS Norfolk, NAS Jacksonville would be doomed from the start, but JB PH-Hickam and almost all of CVBGs deployed overseas would be much easier to quarantine (would say as much even about the Hawaii Archipelago itself). Carriers especially - they are big islands, with personnel always accounted for. Admittedly, the whole carrier group size would mean that anything between 30 and a 100 people daily would go to and from the group back to the mainland, but it still would be quite easy and fast to effect a quarantine. Especially since flight is not yet instantaneous, so plenty of patients zero for carriers would be in transit when the announcement was made, much less the problem noticed.

Russia and China have much less distributed military, but some of their bases would be much more isolated - and easy to lock down - than others' armies...

And since the plague itself is a work of individual or small group, the seeding of US West and East Coasts would take even longer than the incubation of the bug, so first cases would be reported even before they finished, giving rest of the world much more warning that it's implied in the book.

So, bearing in mind that the nature of the book is so that in- and out-of-universe explanation would be about the same, the question is: how come armed forces  - US especially, but by no means exclusively - bungled it up so badly? No matter how crazy the "topic" is, I'm sure that the Pentagon has a plan in case of "biological, viral, latent, wide release, previously undetected, currently no vaccine, hostile activities" type of emergency...

But one needs to clearly separate lack of political willingness to acknowledge the pandemic exists from an implementation of detailed and planned ahead of time policy that doesn't have to be even reported as it's internal military procedural matter... From the timeline, I gather that at the time the plague was identified by government agencies it was still spreading and that was done using civilian transport hubs. That suggests that a lot of personnel transfers were still underway, and the passengers could be isolated or the transports turned around altogether.

Comment: Clearly America's armies lacked enough 13 year old girls to defend them :P

Comment: @JasonK - Heh, heh, heh... And they switched from a round designed to kill enemy to a round designed to piss him off...

Comment: Without knowing the first thing about this book, I have to say the assumption that the US would recognise a pandemic threat (from a previously undetected virus without a vaccine) promptly or respond to it effectively has *not* aged well...

Comment: @tardigrade - I agree in principle, but that this is the case we know since 1996 (or so?). Also, this time the difference would be politics. 2020 saw mostly heavy political interference and limitations. This question though is about US military. Those two are connected, but not the same.
However, 2020 definitely showed what kind of a chaos and/or actual malice can there be.
I hereby promote the series from mere Sci-Fi light reading to Field Manual "How to destroy the world in three easy steps"...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find these books a bit difficult to parse for details like this, but it seems to me that there was some significant disbelief that allowed the zombie virus to spread into areas ahead of any quarantine. Even if some leadership knew of the disease, knowing exactly how it is spread, how infectious it is, and how it works took time, meanwhile it spread throughout the country. Military bases are LOADED with civilians, from family members to government employees, to contractors. So trying to "lock down" these places without a concrete concept of the virus is pointless. Bases are not self-sufficient, they will run out of food within days, just like any town. Even naval vessels, other than the submarines featured in the books, are not really independent secure islands but are constantly visiting ports and transferring personnel.

Consider Zika and Ebola. It took the US military WEEKS to formulate questions and screening protocols for these diseases, and weeks more for treatment procedures should someone infected (or suspected to be infected) shows up to a military hospital. And these are diseases we sorta know about! A deliberately spread bioweapon is gonna catch us all unaware and would be very difficult to combat.

I disagree with a lot of how the books portray the spread of the virus, but given how effective it is and how dangerous the zombies are, few places would be safe on Earth. Heck, folks were still running Italian restaurants and having concerts in Central Park WEEKS after the outbreak! Significant disbelief was in effect.

Comment: What I understood from the Ebola epidemic in Africa the issues were political, not procedural. US army doesn't have the need "to formulate questions and screening protocols", as they are well established by at least three different agencies (CDC, USAMRIID, FEMA)... So I kind of disagree with your assumptions about that. Everything else - I agree, either I mentioned that specifically in question or is hammered at in the books.

Comment: @AcePL I work in a military hospital. It took us quite a while to come out with an actual, workable, plan for ebola. Regardless of what a policy manual says, actual implementation almost always has to be spun up on the spot. The experiences of the Texas hospital (bodily fluid cleaning, etc) was a big eye-opener. To be fair, we are STILL asking if patients just came from an ebola endemic area :P Takes even longer to turn something off :)

Comment: We got a winner! ;) Ok then. Can I ask then how long you worked on those plans and implementation? And if I may say so - keep asking if one is back from ebola country is what I would definitely call "a good habit".

Comment: @AcePL Like I said, it took a couple of weeks. Part of the issue was waiting for official requirements from higher ups, part was just getting folks to take time out of their day to get together and formulate a plan applicable to our specific institution. This is why I think the zombie virus in BTR could spread so fast and penetrate so deeply into military units. As for ebola, the questions is meaningless now since there are no ebola endemic nations anymore, it detracts from current viral hot spots like Zika, and it shows that we mostly fight the LAST virus, not look ahead to the new ones.

Comment: So you're saying that if ebola came knocking at Texas' doors it would end up with such confusion all over again? Hard to believe you would not have procedures established for that already... But if you say so, I'm not arguing.
As for fighting the last virus - I stand corrected on this, too... ;)

Don't know why I was thinking any military isn't like any other bureaucracy... But it's kind of inevitable when just small percentage of the military are actual fighting men.

Comment: @AcePL Absolutely. The specific folks who worked the ebola cases last time are probably gone. The equipment designated for the hot room has been sold, is non-functional, or plain lost. The hot rooms themselves may not exist anymore if there has been a remodel, the new hot room could be on a new ward with entirely different staff. Point being is that it will take a bit of retraining, no one in America is practicing Ebola drills because there is no need to do so. Now imagine a drill for a virus no one has ever seen before. How do you practice for that?